# Smooth scrolling of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

I have a smooth scrolling problem with the `UITableView`. Can anyone help me where is the problem? The code I have written is this-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    LabTestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }//cell.txtHeading.text=@"hello";

    cell.txtHeading.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtdescribtion.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtPrice.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"purchase_price"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtLabName.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"brand"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSString *path=@"https://www.fingerfry.com/pharmgo/uploads/product_image/";
    NSString *url=[path stringByAppendingString:[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"main_image"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    
    cell.image.image=image;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The issue is in image downloading and assigning. Both of this things are happening on Main thread and because of that you are facing lag in scroll. Use some third party library for image downloading and setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the pod:

```
pod 'SDWebImage/WebP', '~>3.7' in pod file.
```

Then you have to import:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Write below code:

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    LabTestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }//cell.txtHeading.text=@"hello";

    cell.txtHeading.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtdescribtion.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtPrice.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"purchase_price"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.txtLabName.text=[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"brand"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[obj valueForKey:IMAGE_KEY]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRefreshCached completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

        }];

    return cell;
}
```

Reference link :
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Problem is because you are loading image in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method synchronously. Use SDWebImage/WebP to load the image asynchronously. Now you will not face scrolling issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use Asynchronous method  backgroundly load the images, use this below code,

```
dispatch_queue_t image_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.imageQueue", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

NSString *path=@"https://www.fingerfry.com/pharmgo/uploads/product_image/";
NSString *url=[path stringByAppendingString:[[_ResponseDic valueForKey:@"main_image"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *dataPath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:url];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] )
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
   
    [cell.imgView setImage:image];
}
else
{
    [cell.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];
    dispatch_async(image_queue, ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
            
            [cell.imgView setImage:image];
            
        });
    });
    
}
```

I have the same issue, i had put the above code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, its working normal scrolling, hope its helpful

Comment: @priyasharma this answer is correct and working fine for you, tick the answer