# Collection view images are flickering while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Im using the following code to populate a collection view cells with images.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = nil;
    if ([imageArray count] >0){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                recipeImageView.image = image;
            });
        });

    }

    [spinnerShow stopAnimating];


    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that, when Im scrolling the images are flickering and are flashing. Why is that so? How can I make those images to be stable without flickering?

Comment: Are seeing it on simulator? If yes then make sure you are viewing simulator at full scale by pressing command+1.

Comment: do you override any scrollview methods in the viewcontroller containing the collection view?

Comment: as cell is reuse and you download every time so it flick .after download put it in document directory and before download check if available in document direcoty  then use it from there,

Comment: Did you try it? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614651/collectionview-images-are-flashing-while-scrolling/37646390#37646390

Comment: you can try : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37560713/1850983

Comment: what if you comment out this line `recipeImageView.image = nil;` just to experiment

Comment: Im using real device not simulator

Comment: No im not overriding any scrollview methods

Comment: I have tried all of those links

Comment: sure..i will comment it out and try again

Comment: Why did you use this code `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {`? Did you fully understand how it works? Please read the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) you need use `dispatch_async` for update your imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UICollectionView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UICollectionView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

**So, now, coming to your answer**

*When you scroll your CollectionView, collectionView datasource method gets called again for every indexPath, coming in visible range and your image gets downloaded again*

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**SOLUTION**

Instantiate a instance NSMutableDictionary, outside of method.

Now in your code

```
@implementation ClassName{
  NSMutableDictionary *cachedImage;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad(){
  [super viewDidLoad];
  cachedImage = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

/*OLD CODE*/
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = nil;
 
    if ([imageArray count] >0){

       //IF image is already downloaded, simply use it and don't download it.
       if(cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] != nil){
           recipeImageView.image = cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       }
       else{
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
               NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

               dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                   recipeImageView.image = image;
                   //****SAVE YOUR DOWNLOADED IMAGE 
                   cachedImage[[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] = image; //****SAVE YOUR DOWNLOADED IMAGE 
               });
           });
       }
}        
/*OLD CODE*/
```

Comment: Im gettting an error expected method to read dictionary not found on object of type nsmutablearray

Comment: yes, i did a mistake there. it is NSMutableDictionary, updated my answer

Comment: @gunjotsingh , just for knowledge purpose , i think there might be memory issues occurred if tried to store images in NSDictionary or NSArray.

Comment: is there any ways to optimize it?

Comment: and sometimes its showing empty image while scrollling

Comment: @Vats There won't be any memory issues, but i definitely agree to prefer NSCache over NSDictionary. NSCache works intelligently in case of low memory scenarios, and release the saved images

Comment: it shouldn't take time to load image  from NSDictionary. Have you instantiated cachedImage in viewDidLoad? UPDATED MY ANSWER. PLZ CHECK

Comment: let me instantiate it

Comment: @gunjotsingh thanks for instant And Detailed Reply. :)

Comment: you are damn intelligent

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge, you are fetching image but not caching it that's why when your `UICollectionViewCell` gets reload, you get UIImageView's fresh instance so and this thing goes on and on in your code..

in this case, i recommend you to use `SDWebImage` OR `AFNetworking` Frameworks. because these frameworks does all the tricky stuff for you with the simple line of code (SDWebImage Framework),

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
[yourImageView setBackgroundImageWithURL:url forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:kPlaceholder];
```

Comment: Is there any ways to solve it without using third party libraries

Comment: @KaruppuMGR , of course , you have to store your downloaded image to cache. just check this Accepted Answer, it has detailed Answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511548/best-way-to-cache-images-on-ios-app